# Not all SpatialLines displaying in Leaflet with addPolylines

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm developing a web app using `R-Shiny`.

My problem is that not all lines in a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` (SLDF) are being displayed in the `Leaflet` map. Any suggestions would be welcome. The datasets are stored [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApcADMsOKppcgVD19petv_aqWlWm).

**My code:**

```
#convert raster layer (ras) to SLDF
rtc <- rasterToContour(ras)

leaflet() %>%
addPolylines(data=rtc, group="contour", layerId="contour_pr",noClip = TRUE)
```

**Results:**

Only the inner contour line is displayed in `Leaflet`

[image]

Alternatively, all lines are shown using the R plot function (`plot(rtc)`)
[image]

**Version info:**

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
other attached packages:
[1] igraph_1.2.2 rgeos_0.3-25 bindrcpp_0.2.2 ggplot2_3.1.0 withr_2.1.2
[6] labeling_0.3 V8_1.5 RColorBrewer_1.1-2 stringr_1.3.1 ncdf4_1.16
[11] yaml_2.2.0 data.table_1.11.4 mapview_2.5.0 sf_0.6-3 DT_0.4
[16] geometa_0.3-0 rgdal_1.3-6 raster_2.6-7 sp_1.3-1 dplyr_0.7.6
[21] plyr_1.8.4 leaflet.extras_1.0.0 leaflet_2.0.2 shinyBS_0.61 
shinyjs_1.0
[26] shinydashboard_0.7.0 shiny_1.1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this.

1. If you want to add them all at once, you should add the
   `SpatialLinesDataFrame` as a dataset in the `leaflet` function (**example 1**).
2. More ugly, but is also possible to add them individually (**example 2**).

**Example 1**

```
leaflet(data=rtc) %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines()
```

**Example 2**

```
map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
for( level in rtc$level){
  map <- addPolylines(map, data=subset(rtc, level==level))
}
# to show the map
map
```

**Result**

[image]